# Accessing keys with non-ascii characters using jq

Tags: macos, utf-8, jq, locale

This is a snippet of a json response from a Norwegian service (inatur). The response contains the letter "ø". While not a problem programmatically, I have issues getting JQ to accept what I am feeding it. How can I access the key called "kjøpdatoliste"?

```
{
  "id": "644a906b5dfdfc89dfe5a0d8",
  "netsStatus": "BETALT",
  "kjøpdatoliste": [
    1691964000000,
    1692050400000,
    1692136800000,
    1692223200000,
    1692309600000,
    1692396000000,
    1692482400000
  ],
  "kommunerFormatert": "Sigdal",
  "erKjøpetGjennomført": true,
  "opprettetFormatert": "27.04.2023"
}
```

Example of ASCII key:

```
$ jq .id /tmp/testdata.json
"644a906b5dfdfc89dfe5a0d8"
```

Example of non-ASCII key:

```
$ jq '.erKjøpetGjennomført' /tmp/testdata.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.erKjøpetGjennomført
jq: 1 compile error
```

Environment details:

```
LANG=no_NO.UTF-8

$ npx envinfo --system

  System:
    OS: macOS 13.4
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 172.38 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
```

Comment: Use `."erKjøpetGjennomført"` or `.["erKjøpetGjennomført"]`. (See the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectIdentifier-Index%3A.foo%2C.foo.bar) on the "Object Identifier-Index" containing "special characters")